# Enity Framework db.Products.SqlQuery("") is return null

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

```
db.Products.SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Products WHERE Name LIKE '%{0}%' AND ORDER BY Name OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT {1} ROWS ONLY", str, 10).ToList();
```

On SQL Server, this query returns results, but it's not using Entity Framework

Comment: I suggest you read the [documentation on `SqlQuery(..)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbset.sqlquery(v=vs.113).aspx).  It lets you use *named parameters*, it doesn't format a string for you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass parameters to the DbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand method?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5474264/1260204) **and** [How to pass parameters to DbSet.SqlQuery Method in Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10553436/1260204)

Comment: You mean LIKE and also can you provide how your EF query looks?

Comment: By "On Sql Server this query return result but not using Entity Framework," do you mean that the SQL query returns results in SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS), but does not return results in the EF version of the query?

Answer (score 1):

This should work. Note that the 1st parameter is a string parameter value where the value is surrounded by the wild card `%` character and it is not enclosed in quotes in the query itself because it will be replaced by a proper parameter. The next 10 offset can't be parameterized but you could use the `.Skip` and `.Take` extensions to do this instead on the returned result set. In the query below I hand coded the value. I also removed the extra `AND` you had.

```
db.Products.SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Products WHERE Name LIKE {0} ORDER BY Name OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY", "%" + str + "%").ToList();
```

With Skip/Take

```
var top10 = db.Products.SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Products WHERE Name LIKE {0} ORDER BY Name", "%" + str + "%").Skip(0).Take(10).ToList();
```

And here is the same functional query that does **not** use `SqlQuery`

```
var top10 = db.Products.Where(prod => prod.Name.Contains(str))
    .OrderBy(x => x.Name)
    .Skip(0) // not necessary because of value 0 but illustrates how to skip records
    .Take(10)
    .ToList();
```